# "Input value not long enough for date format" When updating with TableAdapter

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oracle11g, .net-4.5, tableadapter

My queries are managed by a `DataAdapter`, so I have little to no control over it's generation.The problem query goes this way:

```
UPDATE  MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
SET     MYDATETIME = :myDateTime
WHERE   (MYKEY = :myKey)
```

The data access layer is automatically generated. I can't change how it works...

The type of `MYDATETIME`in the database side is `Timestamp`.

The type of the parameter `myDateTime` of the `DataAdapter` query and the field from the dataset is `DateTime`.

Not sure if it should matter. Also, it seems that on the Oracle side, the hour is 24 hour but the hour managed by the app has a 12 hour base. But Why would it matter? When calling the update method, I pass `Date.Now`. How more legit could it be?? But it still is rejected with:

> ORA-01840: Input value not long enough for date format

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "Once converted inside the dataset, it becomes a `DateTime`"? Do you mean converted inside the database? (What does "converted inside the **dataset** mean?) More importantly, if this is an Oracle database, there is no `DateTime` data type. Oracle only has `Date` (which **always** includes time!) and `Timestamp`. Then: In what system (database, language, etc.) is your incoming value `:myDateTime` a `Timestamp`? (Are you sure it is not just a string?)

Comment: @mathguy a dataset is some sort of objects in wich the data extracted from the tables will be stored. Mine are auto generated, and the datatype from the timestamp type column will be datetime.

Comment: I know what a dataset is, I don't understand "converted inside the dataset." The conversion, I assume, does not happen "inside the dataset". Who are you looking to for the conversion - is the conversion performed by your application, or by the database? (Or is it hidden from you, since you are using `DataAdapter` and it's not transparent?)

Comment: I assume there is some sort of conversion from timestamp to datetime... Not sure when it happens, but if so, it must be when obtaining the data just before storing it, but it has never caused any problems so far in any other type of data access... I'm stuck with the datasets that just never work as expected...

Comment: Conversion was not the correct word... I removed it.

Comment: Click the relevant tableadapter in the dataset designer, and take a look at the parameters collection. What is the providertype of the mydatetime parameter?

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to give DbType too..

Comment: Well, Maybe it is not clear, but I already said that the parameter type is DateTime and the type on the table it Timestamp... I will try to make it more clear.

Comment: Ps; youve said both TableAdapter and DataAdapter but these two object types are actually different things- a tableadapter is a strongly typed wrapper around a dataadapter. Can you confirm that you really are using tableadapters? It influences the advice given you see...

Comment: I got it. It is varchar2 (the provider type) and the dbtype is DateTime. Ok. I didn't know about this one. It must be my problem!

Comment: It looks like the dataset designer has become confused about the schema and has put the providertype down as varchar, so your datetime c# object is being made to string in the parameter, passed to oracle as string and oracle is trying to auto convert it to time stamp

Comment: That is it. It was the problem all along. The option strict was set to false when I first started working on this badly coded application, so that might be why... Thanks for your help it solved it all!

Comment: No probs, I reposted it as an answer so you can tick it as answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment chat, it seems that a string conversion is occurring because the parameter database type is set to varchar

Set the ProviderType of the parameter to be something more relevant to the type Oracle is expecting - it'll either be Date, DateTime, Timestamp, OracleDateTime or some variation on this theme (the names change according to whether you use .net oracle client or oracle's one) , hopefully...